# Suspend suddenly stopped working

Tags: 11.10, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and it appears the suspend feature suddenly stopped working.  Now, when I close the laptop lid, the machines powers off. To my knowledge, I haven't made any configuration changes to suspend when laptop lid is closed. It was working perfectly yesterday. What can I do to diagnose and hopefully fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please get the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and add it to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"` to `/etc/default/grub` and then running `sudo update-grub` seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't work for you, please refer to the last comment I made on this post for help:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/989674?comments=all